# Как можно скруглить картинку svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, изображения

Я новичок в верстке, поэтому делаю все по статьям и урокам в интернете. Нужно сделать такие иконки. Сами картинки у меня в svg.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу скруглить их родительский блок, хотя вроде бы делаю все по уроку. Возможно проблема в стилях колонки. В общем, вот мой код:

```
     <div class = "about">
     <div class ="column column-gray">
    <div class = "img__circle">
    <img src="images/contacts/01.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <span class ="column__title column__title-small">Phone Number</span>
    <span class="column__content">+1111111</span>
    </div> 

    <div class="column column-gray">
    <div class = "img__circle">
    <img src="images/contacts/03.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <span class ="column__title column__title-small">Address</span>
    <span class="column__content column__content-small">adress</span>
   </div>


    <div class="column column-gray">
    <div class = "img__circle">
    <img src="images/contacts/02.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <span class ="column__title column__title-small">E-mail</span>
    <span class="column__content column__content-small">mail</span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Стили для скругления картинок.

```
.img__cirсle {
background-color : #15263e;
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
flex: 0 0 60px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 3;
}

.img_circle img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Стили блока с колонками

```
about {
display: flex;
flax-direction : row;
justify-content: space-between;

}
.column{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: #ffffff;
flex : 0 1 33.333%;
justify-content: сenter;
max-height: 100vh;
min-width: 33.333%;
}

.column-gray{
background-color: #dcdcde: 
}
```

Вот что у меня получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать круг из div с классом .img_circle? Что я не так делаю? Ведь синий блок хотя бы должен быть виден, а его нет.

Comment: или mask или clip-path

Comment: инженерная часть тегов лучше изменить это раз. два класс тэга не совпадает с классом цсс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так. Дальше сами.

```css
.img__circle {
    background-color: #15263e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex: 0 0 60px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.img__circle img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  flax-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.di>span {
    display: block;
}
.column {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  flex: 0 1 33.333%;
  justify-content: сenter;
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 33.333%;*/
      display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.column-gray {
  background-color: #dcdcde:
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="column column-gray">
    <div class="img__circle">
      <img src="images/contacts/01.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="di"><span class="column__title column__title-small">Phone Number</span>
    <span class="column__content">+1111111</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column column-gray">
    <div class="img__circle">
      <img src="images/contacts/03.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="di"><span class="column__title column__title-small">Address</span>
    <span class="column__content column__content-small">adress</span></div>
  </div>


  <div class="column column-gray">
    <div class="img__circle">
      <img src="images/contacts/02.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="di"><span class="column__title column__title-small">E-mail</span>
    <span class="column__content column__content-small">mail</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть проблема была в display : flex  и flex для img__circle?

Comment: не только. код можно упростить.